# Convert String to Float in Javascript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Please see below code,i getting wrong value.

eg;

```
 var FirstValue=0.00;
 var secondvalue=parseFloat("22.88",10).toFixed(2);    
 var thirdvalue=(FirstValue) +   (secondvalue);
```

am getting value like"22.8822.88"

Please help me to solve.Its not convert to numeric .

Comment: Is this actually your code? I don't get the correct result but I don't get what you're seeing. Also you have an extra closing `)` after `toFixed`. http://jsfiddle.net/DJSRV/3/

Comment: Thanks..its not a actual code..yes there there is extra closing. i removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

toFixed convert you float value to string back. So when you adding two values you will get not number addition but string concatenation:

```
2.0 + 2.0 = 4.0 // number
"2.0" + "2.0" = "2.02.0" // string
```

Remove to fixed after conversion. Than add two values and than do to fixed:

```
var FirstValue=0.00;
var secondvalue=parseFloat("22.88",10);    
var thirdvalue= ( (FirstValue) +   (secondvalue) ).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: ok.Its fine for floating .but my secondvalue may be interger like "10",am using this inside loop.

Comment: then its giving error like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: I test it on IE6 and FireFox - it works for me. Copy past this code - and it's work. Maybe there is other problem in your code?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var FirstValue=0.00;
 var secondvalue=parseFloat("22.88");
 secondvalue = parseFloat(secondvalue.toFixed(2));   
 var thirdvalue=(FirstValue) +   (secondvalue);
```

[`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string, not a number so it needs to be converted again.